# How to configure SwiRL- A semantic role labeler in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, command-line, cygwin

everyones.
I would like to run SwiRL-a tool for semantic role labeling. This tool run in Linux, but I used Cygwin. I used this following instructions:

```
1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
     `./configure' to configure the package for your system.
```

But it doesn't work. My commands like this:

```
C:\user\...\swirl-1.1.0>configure
```

Then: it says: 'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

This directory have some folders: config, corpus, data, src, model_swirl and file configure.

I tried to use this command in some sub directory but received the same result.
How can I do now? Please explain for me. May be I don't understand what is the term "package's source code" in the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `./configure`, including the `./` portion.  The single dot and slash tells it to look in the current directory for the command, otherwise it will only look in the directories in your PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks Pak, I used ./configure but it saids: "." is not recognized.... although I refer to path of this file's directory.

Comment: Are you using the Cygwin or Windows shell?  That output looks like what you'd get by using the Windows cmd shell, which won't work.

Comment: oh, that's right. Last time I used Windows cmd shell to run some Linux commands  and they worked well after I set up Cygwin in my laptop. 
I tried to run Cygwin from its icon but  I cant. It noticed that: windows is searching for mintty. To locate the file, click Browse. But when I browse to the directory Cygwin64, I dont find it.
I dont know what to do now?

Comment: 'configure' is a script that calls /bin/sh, and Windows can't interpret.  You'll need to install some Cygwin shell to use it. Try installing the mintty package via the setup program.

Comment: Many thanks @pak, I 've got Cygwin shell with my configuration.